# Reading a table from excel into vb

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have written/modified the following code to read in a table from excel. Unfortunately the table is very large over 600 rows and 700 columns, the operation is taking over an hour and a half to complete. Does anyone have a faster way of reading in such a large table?

```
Public Function ReadExcelTable(ExcelFileName As String, ExcelWSName As String, FirstRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer, FirstCol As Integer, LastCol As Integer) As String(,)

    ' define variables
    Dim CurrRow As Integer, CurrCol As Integer
    Dim OutputTable(0 To LastRow - FirstRow, 0 To LastCol - FirstCol) As String

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    'xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(ExcelWSName)

    CurrRow = -1
    For rCnt = FirstRow To LastRow
        CurrCol = -1
        CurrRow = CurrRow + 1
        For cCnt = FirstCol To LastCol
            CurrCol = CurrCol + 1
            If Not IsNothing(xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).Value) Then
                OutputTable(CurrRow, CurrCol) = PrepareString(xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).Value.ToString)
            Else
                OutputTable(CurrRow, CurrCol) = ""
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ReadExcelTable = OutputTable

    xlWorkBook.Close(False)
    Call Kill_Excel()
    'xlApp.Quit()

    xlWorkSheet = Nothing
    xlWorkBook = Nothing
    xlApp = Nothing


End Function
```

Comment: you may want to look into SQL databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using OleDb instead of Interop.
This is just a pseudocode trying to emulate your method.
Probably some adjustement are required. (Look for example to the [connectionstring part here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)).
But I hope to give you the idea.

```
Public Function ReadExcelTable(ExcelFileName As String, ExcelWSName As String, FirstRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer, FirstCol As Integer, LastCol As Integer) As String(,)

    Try 
        Dim curRow As Integer = 1
        Dim con as String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                             ExcelFileName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;'"
        Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(con)
           cn.Open() 
           Dim cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from [" & ExcelWSName &"$]", cn) 
           Using dr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader 
           While dr.Read 
              if curRow >= FirstRow Then
                   ''' reading values from excel 
                  Dim curCol As Integer = 0
                  For cCnt = FirstCol To LastCol
                      If Not reader.IsDBNull(cCnt)) Then
                         OutputTable(CurRow, curCol) = PrepareString(reader(cCnt).ToString())
                      Else
                         OutputTable(CurRow, curCol) = ""
                      End If
                      curCol += 1
                  Next
              End If
              curRow+= 1
              if curRow > LastRow Then
                 Exit While
              End If
           End While 
           End Using 
        End Using 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()) 
    End Try 
End Sub
```